# k8s communicate from one service to another

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have two services deployed on the same k8s (minikube cluster).  What is the url/approach I should use for one service to communicate with another service.  I tried searching a bit on the web but most of them are communicating with an external db which is not what I'm after.  This is what my deployments look like.  I am looking for the goclient to be able to communicate with goserver.  I know I need to go through the service but not sure what the url should look like.  And is this dynamically discoverable?  In addition to this if I expose goserver though `ingress` will this change ?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: goserver
  namespace: golang-ns
  labels:
    app: goserver
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: goserver
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: goserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: goserver
        image: goserver:1.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: goclient
  namespace: golang-ns
  labels:
    app: goclient
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: goclient
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: goclient
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: goclient
        image: goclient:1.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: goserver-service
  namespace: golang-ns
spec:
  selector:
    app: goserver  
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: goclient-service
  namespace: golang-ns
spec:
  selector:
    app: goclient
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: You should be able to use the Service's `name` (and `namespace`) as a host name, and the matching Service's `port`; `goserver-service:8080`.  See for example [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) in the Kubernetes documentation.  How are you configuring the connection information, and what error do you get when you try to connect?

Answer (score 5):

Note that the term ***Service*** can be quite ambiguous when used in the context of **kubernetes**.

**Service** in your question is used to denote one of your **microservices**, deployed as containerized applications, running in `Pods`, managed by 2 separate `Deployments`.

`Service`, that was mentioned in David Maze's comment, refers to a specific resource type which is used for exposing your apps/microservices both inside and outside your **kubernetes cluster**. This resource type is called a [`Service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). But I assume you know that as such `Services` are also added in your examples.

This is the reason why I prefer to use a term ***microservice*** if I really want to call *"a service"* one of the apps (clients, servers, whatever... ) deployed on my **kubernetes cluster**. And yes, this is really important distinction as talking about communication from one `Service` to another `Service` (kubernetes resource type) doesn't make any sense at all. Your `Pod` can communicate with a different `Pod` via a `Service` that exposes this second `Pod`, but `Services` don't communicate with each other at all. I hope this is clear.

So in order to expose one of your **microservices** **within your cluster** and make it easily accessible for other **microservices**, running on the same cluster, use a [`Service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). But what you really need in your case is it's simplest form. ❗**There is no need for using `LoadBalancer` type here**. In your case you want to expose your `Deployment` named `goserver` to make it accessible by `Pods` from second `Deployment`, named `goclient`, not by external clients, sending requests from the public Internet.

Note that [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/) type that you used in your `Service`'s yaml manifests has completely different purpose - it is used for exposing your app for clients reaching to it from outside your **kubernetes cluster** and is mainly applicable in cloud environments.

So again, what you need in your case is the simplest `Service` (often called `ClusterIP` as it is the default `Service` type) which exposes a `Deployment` **within** the cluster. ⚠️ Remember that `ClusterIP` `Service` also has loadbalancing capabilities.

OK, enough of explanations, let's move on to the practical part. As I said, it's really simple and it can be done with one command:

```
kubectl expose deployment goserver --port 8080 --namespace golang-ns
```

Yes! That's all! It will create a `Service` named `goserver` (there is no reason to name it differently than the `Deployment` it exposes) which will expose `Pods` belonging to `goserver` `Deployment` within your **kubernetes cluster**, making it easily accessible (and discoverable) via it's [DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#dns) name.

If you prefer declarative `Service` definition, here it is as well:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: goserver
  namespace: golang-ns
spec:
  selector:
    app: goserver  
  ports:
    - port: 8080
```

Your `golang-client` `Pods` need only the `Service` name i.e. `goserver` to access `goserver` `Pods` as they are deployed in the same namespace (`golang-ns`). If you need to access them from a `Pod` deployed to a different namespace, you need to use `<servicename>.<namespace>` i.e. `goserver.golang-ns`. You can also use **fully quallified domain name (FQDN)** (see the official docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services)):

```
my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example
```

which in your case may look as follows:

```
goserver.golang-ns.svc.cluster.local
```

As to:

> In addition to this if I expose goserver though ingress will this
> change ?

❗Unless you want to expose your `goserver` to the external world, don't use `Ingress`, you don't need it.